# Extending a function $f$, from the border of a closed cell to the border to another closed cell, to $F$, from the closed cell to another closed cell

Tags: general-topology

[image]

The question and my solution, where do I get from here? We can start with a

Comment: This was already answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1120533/extending-a-continuous-map-between-the-boundary-of-two-cells).

Comment: @Mnifldz Thanks!